# PostgreSQL for user management and another database for file management (Blob storage)

Tags: postgresql, mongodb, blob, azure-blob-storage

I am working on a project with video hosting and online editing platform with a microservice architecture in mind.

One of my teammates uses PostgreSQL SQL for user management, but I need to handle large files, and we are going to use Azure blob storage.
I would like to know, should I create another database for file management, and if yes, what should it be? (I have MongoDB in mind)

Comment: i don't see what the gain switching database system will bring

Comment: I would rather *not* store `large files` inside the database at all. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8971673/939860

Comment: I won't store file in the database, I just want to store references to files there,

Comment: Then why have two databases, not one?

Comment: If video files are on the block blob, why you need a database for file management?